# grid view data in text box instead of cell

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a web page containing a grid view and need to display the data in the text box on page load instead of cell.

** Grid is read only
** There will not be edit/delete links.
is it possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gridview` templates fields, and you will find more about [Using TemplateFields in the GridView Control](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs)
You can do something like this

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txbType" Text='<%# Eval("fieldName") %>' Enabled="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

In here   `<%# Eval("fieldName") %>` -- `fieldName` should be the value need to be display from your DB

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `TemplateFields` to the GridView and bind the TextBoxe(s) into `ItemTemplate` of each TemplateField column.